# AngularFor each - loop through multiple array

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that I fetch from my `REST API`...

I want to loop through an inner array, check for an attribute and if that attribute is `true` get a second attribute from the item.

This is the array;

```
orderItem:  { 
    id: 159
    name: Empanadas (Choice of 2)
    description: Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella
    price: 700
    available: 1
    created_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
    updated_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
    menu_category_id: 41
    restaurant_id: 11
    menu_modifier_groups: 
        [  { 
            id: 9
            name: Choose 2 Empanadas
            instruction: null
            min_selection_points: 2
            max_selection_points: 2
            force_selection: 1
            created_at: 2016-02-01 01:03:35
            updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:12:23
            menu_item_id: 159
            restaurant_id: 11
                menu_modifier_items: 
                [  { 
                    id: 34
                    name: Diced Beef
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:08
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:08
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: false
                 } ,  { 
                    id: 35
                    name: Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:37
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:37
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: true
                 } ,  { 
                    id: 36
                    name: Stilton, Spinach and Onion
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:05:05
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:05:05
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: false
             }  ]
         }  ]
 }
```

What I want to do is find all `menu_modifier_items` that have `selected` = `true` get the `price` for each add them up together and finally add them to the `price` of `orderItem`.

`all menu_modifier_items price + orderItem price`

This is what I have so far;

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function(orderItem) {
 var tot = orderItem.price;
 angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups[0].menu_modifier_items,function(item){
    if(item.selected == true) {
        tot+=item.price;
    }
   return "Add for " + "&#8358;" + tot;
 });
}
```

In my code, `menu_modifier_groups[0]` this means that I'm getting the first array, but what if `orderItem` has many `menu_modifier_groups`? In the case where I have `menu_modifier_groups[0]`, `menu_modifier_groups[1]` etc...

Any help/guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have 2 `forEach`s nested inside each other - loop through the groups, then loop through the items inside the current group:

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function(orderItem) {
    var tot = orderItem.price;

    angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups, function(group) {
        angular.forEach(group.menu_modifier_items, function(item) {
            if(item.selected == true) {
                tot+=item.price;
            }
        });
    });

    return "Add for " + "&#8358;" + tot;
}
```